# Query all posts if multiple meta key don't exist

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, query-posts, array

I'm trying to get all posts that don't have a meta ket that starts with aa_. I can do it this way

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'category__in' => 23,
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
array(
 'key' => 'aa_article_1',
 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
 'value' => '' 
),
array(
 'key' => 'aa_article_2',
 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
 'value' => '' 
),
array(
 'key' => 'aa_article_3',
 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
 'value' => '' 
),
array(
 'key' => 'aa_article_4',
 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
 'value' => '' 
),
array(
 'key' => 'aa_article_5',
 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
 'value' => '' 
),
array(
 'key' => 'aa_article_6',
 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
 'value' => '' 
)

));

$the_query = new WP_Query ($args);
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" target="_blank">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
echo "<h2>Found: $the_query->found_posts posts</h2>";
} else {
// no posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Is there a way to do this simpeler? I have about 50 meta keys that start with aa_ and it would save some time. And of course it's also nice to know if it's possible, for future use :)

Comment: This is a tricky one, I'm not sure if a huge `meta_query` with 50 sub arrays are possible, and even if it is, it would be rather slow. We could try to change the `=` operator in the SQL query to `LIKE` for meta key matching, then we could match meta keys starting with `aa_`. Again, `LIKE` comparisons are really slow, and it becomes an issue on very large databases. IMHO, I would create a new custom field, and assing `1` to it when a post has a field starting with `aa_`, and `0` if not. We can then query posts by this new custom field

Comment: I would also just try to keep my meta key as `aa_article` and then asiing the number to the meta value

Comment: maybe a single `aa_article` meta key with an array that is only set if one of the 50 is set would be better practice here, then you could just check if that exists.

Comment: @Pieter Goosen The new aa_ would be a great idea, but there are already more than 500 posts...

Comment: @Pieter Goosen The aa_article won't work in this case but the actual meta keys are like aa_chickensoup, aa_tomatosoup.

Comment: @Pieter Goosen "I'm not sure if a huge meta_query with 50 sub arrays are possible". I have done them all and 50 is possible. Also the speed isn't that bad. I hardly notice it. But it would be nice if there is a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

global $wpdb;

$excludeposts = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND meta_key NOT LIKE %aa_%
ORDER BY post_date DESC
";

$main_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post__not_in' => $excludeposts, 
    'paged' => $paged 
    ) 
);

while ($main_query->have_posts()) :

```
$main_query->the_post();
//Stuff...
```

endwhile;

//hope this helps

Comment: Please clean up your code and explain how it works and how it should be used

Comment: I am going to explore this and see if I could get it working.

Comment: No output whatsoever. I've put `<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>` where you wrote //stuff

Comment: The above code just Select everything except the meta to exclude :
- You can run the sql on your db to check the result. just echo the $excludeposts; for a development test and copy paste that sql to your db

- Use as get_the_permalink() & get_the_title()